# UserTransaction cannot be rollbacked while using intermediate error event

Tags: java, wildfly, jbpm, workflow-engine

I am encountering an issue with the use of an intermediate error boundary event in jBPM. My scenario involves two WorkItemHandlers, where the second one is expected to trigger the error boundary event by throwing a ProcessWorkItemHandlerException. I am uncertain if my setup is correct or how to accurately trigger the error boundary event, especially as the article referenced in the documentation is no longer available.

Here is a diagram of my current configuration: [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW8tk.png)

**Github Gist:** [Code and Exception](https://gist.github.com/dhois/bc6ac4688c08bfc3d6d0eff90b76bd5d)

I would appreciate any guidance on what I might be doing wrong, or how I can ensure that the flow of the BPM diagram correctly splits at the boundary event. Additionally, I am receiving an exception message and would like to understand how to resolve it.

Thank you.